# Converting characters to numbers

Tags: vbscript, converters

In a program I am currently making, I need to convert a certain set of characters to numbers. This set of characters is prone to change and also includes CaPiTaL letters in the conversion, of which the capitals will be converted to a different number as with special characters (such as "#", "&", "$", etc). The numbers follow a simple pattern; a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, etc.

The current method I am using to do this is using a separate:

```
If letter = "a" then
  number = 1
End If
```

This method however is a chore to write up and also seems to be a bit inefficient (in terms of running continuous/bulk amounts of letters through it). Is there any function, sub, etc. that can be used to perform an action like this in VBScript (specifically in VB Express 2010)?

Comment: Why do you want to "convert" characters to numbers? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: It is for a program I am currently making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfw01fx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). The `Asc()` function returns the [character code](http://www.ascii-code.com/) of a given ASCII character:

```
>>> WScript.Echo Asc("a")
97
>>> WScript.Echo Asc("A")
65
```

Another option is to create a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with the desired mappings:

```vb
Set map = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
map.Add "a", 1
map.Add "b", 2
...
```

which can be used like this:

```
>>> WScript.Echo map("a")
1
>>> WScript.Echo map("b")
2
```

Comment: FWIW I would have answered something like this `Asc(LCase("A")) - 64` which would return the position in the alphabet although it would only be good for characters within the acceptable logical range. Good work nonetheless

Comment: Actually, `Asc()` returns the code for the "ANSI" character using the current default character set for the thread/process/user/OS, which is almost certainly not ASCII. [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), maybe?

Comment: @TomBlodget Technically, "ANSI" in this context means "ASCII extended character set for (Windows) codepage 1252". However, as far as the question is concerned there is no significant difference between ANSI and ASCII.

Comment: So why mention ASCII when it's not used? "ANSI" means any of the many 8-bit character set encodings supported by Windows. It's only Windows-1252 if the user or programmer makes it so.

Comment: This worked **perfectly**. I completely forgot to look on the MS website... sorry. In conjunction with the scripting dictionary this works very well at changing the characters to numbers, then forming a new string with said set of numbers. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Step 0: Using positional mapping:

```
Option Explicit

' Start with a function working on a string that calls
' a character decode function
Function decodeS(s)
  ReDim aTmp(Len(s) - 1)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
      aTmp(i) = decodeC(Mid(s, i + 1, 1))
  Next
  decodeS = aTmp
End Function

' naive decode via InStr/Index/Position
Function decodeC(c)
  decodeC = InStr("abc", c)
End Function
WScript.Echo "acbbca", Join(decodeS("acbbca"))
```

Step 1: guarded positional mapping:

```
' guarded decode via InStr/Index/Position
Function decodeC(c)
  decodeC = -1
  Dim p : p = InStr("abcdefghiA", c)
  If p Then decodeC = p
End Function
WScript.Echo "acbbcAx", Join(decodeS("acbbcAx"))
```

Step 2: positional mapping 'doesn't work', switch to lookup:

```
' decode via parallel array and InStr/Index/Position
Dim gsC : gsC = "aAbBcC"
Dim gaC : gaC = Split("-1 1 10 2 20 3 30")
Function decodeC(c)
  decodeC = CLng(gaC(InStr(gsC, c)))
End Function
WScript.Echo "CcBxbAa", Join(decodeS("CcBxbAa"))
```

Step 3: you prefer dictionary lookup:

```
' decode via dictionary
Dim gdC : Set gdC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
gdC("a") = 1
gdC("A") = 10
Function decodeC(c)
  decodeC = -1
  If gdC.Exists(c) Then decodeC = gdC(c)
End Function
WScript.Echo "CcBxbAa", Join(decodeS("CcBxbAa"))
```